# Google .NET API fails due to error 403 (forbidden)

Tags: c#, google-api, google-beacon-platform

My code snippet below is supposed to return the list of beacons. When having Google API Console generate an API Key I have whitelisted my public IP address and associated with the api key. When the code calls ExecuteAsync() method, I keep receiving an exception with error code 403 (forbidden). What may have I done wrong and how to mitigate the issue?

```
public async void TestApiKey()
{
    var apikey = "739479874ABCDEFGH123456"; //it's not the real key I'm using
    var beaconServices = new ProximitybeaconService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "My Project",
        ApiKey = apikey
    });

    var result = await beaconServices.Beacons.List().ExecuteAsync();

    // Display the results.
    if (result.Beacons != null)
    {
        foreach (var api in result.Beacons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(api.BeaconName + " - " + api.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Beacon Service to your project in the API console?

Comment: please post the full error message 403 forbidden is probably only part of what google has returned to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Public API key.  Public API keys only work with public data.

> [beacons.list](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/list) Authenticate using an OAuth access token from a
>   signed-in user with viewer, Is owner or Can edit permissions.
>
> Requires the following OAuth scope:
>   •https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry

The method you are trying to access is accessing private user data.  You need to be authentication before you can use it.  Switch to Oauth2 authentication.  Setting it to public probably wont work because you cant to my knowledge supply a scope to a public api key.

Comment: @dalmto Is OAuth access token the same as Client ID that I generated through Google's API Console?

Comment: No access tokens are generated by the authentication server using the client id and client secret once a user has granted your application access to their data

Comment: @dalmto But this piece of code is supposed to work on one of our servers where users do not have access to the backend. What am I supposed to do in that case then?

Comment: @dalmto I made some progress but I got stuck with another issue mentioned in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705660/receiving-forbidden-error-message-403-when-getting-the-list-of-beacons-in-goog