# Receiving forbidden error message (403) when getting the list of beacons in Google Beacon Platform

Tags: c#, google-api, google-beacon-platform

I have created a service account for my Google Proximity API project and downloaded the key file to use it in my application. But when the very last line of the code snippet below is executed, I receive the following exception:

> Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Unauthorized. [403] Errors [  Message[Unauthorized.] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]]

And here is the code that is supposed to run on the server machine (backend):

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12",
                "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("MyServiceId@focal-baton-55555.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry" },
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            var beacon = new Google.Apis.Proximitybeacon.v1beta1.Data.Beacon();

            var beaconServices = new ProximitybeaconService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "My SampleProject",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential 
            });

            var result = await beaconServices.Beacons.List().ExecuteAsync();
```

I have spent hours but I could not conclude anything at all. What am I missing in this context and how to fix the problem?

Comment: Service account needs to be preauthorized I am not sure if you can give another user access to your data in that api but if you can share it use the service account email address and give it access

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by giving the necessary permissions when creating service account. That was the step that I missed unfortunately. Then I used the same .p12 file to authenticate the application to the API.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Would you mind describing for others exactly how you fixed your problem.   How do you authorize the service account to this API.